# Can I run a raw CURL command from within React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, http, curl, http2

Trying to run a raw cURL from our React Native app (need to specify HTTP1.1 connection).  Is this possible to do from within React Native?

```
 curl -X POST 'https://example.com/Authentication/connect/token' --http1.1 -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that. Because the `curl` is a UNIX/Linux shell program.

Answer (score 0):

You can install `axios` and use it in React Native.

Comment: Thanks, I am familiar with axios but it doesn't allow you to specify the same commands as a raw cURL request